# How to do calculation based on most top row in a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Please consider this Table:

```
StuffCode        ClassCode         Value
----------------------------------------
AA001            00000             32561
AA001            00001             1232
AA001            00002             12312
AB002            00000             2112
AB002            00001             1234
AB002            00002             120
AC003            00000             6986
AC003            00001             1423
AC003            00002             658
```

I want to Create Such this Result:

```
StuffCode        ClassCode         Percent
----------------------------------------
AA001            00000             100
AA001            00001             3.78
AA001            00002             37.81
AB002            00000             100
AB002            00001             58.42
AB002            00002             5.68
AC003            00000             100
AC003            00001             20.36
AC003            00002             9.41
```

That `Percent` Column claculated base on division of `Value` of each record by value of `Class Code = 00000` in each `StuffCode` group. For Example

> For Row 2: (1232 / 32561) * 100 = 3.78
>
> For Row 5: (1234 / 2112) * 100 = 58.42

...

How I can do this with one select?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `Max() Over()`

```
SELECT *,
       [Value] * 1.0 / Max(CASE
                       WHEN [ClassCode] = '00000' THEN [Value]
                     END) OVER(partition by StaffCode) * 100
FROM   Yourtable
```

Comment: In think you need to add partition by StaffCode

Answer (score 1):

You can query as below:

```
Select *, [Percent] = ([Value]*1.0/FIRST_VALUE([Value]) over(partition by StaffCode order by ClassCode))*100
    from #testdata
```

Comment: Will not work if there is a new `ClassCode` which will sort before `00000` in string sorting, example `000`. Though it is not the case in sample data..